# Laravel - Multiple Controllers within a View

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to code a simple social media page. The show view should display a post with all the comments for that particular post listed below.

I've tried a couple different approaches with no luck, this is the approach I feel like I might be closet to success with, any suggestions?

I can provide other extracts of code if you think the problem lies elsewhere but I think my problem lies within these 4 files.

**web.php**

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
Route::resource('post', 'CommentController');
```

**show.blade.php**

```
<h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
<p>Description: {{$post->description}}</p>

<h3>Comments</h3>
<ul>
  @foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <li>
      User: {{$comments->user_name}} <br>
      Comment: {{$comments->comment}} <br>
    </li><br>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

**PostController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{
  $post= Post::find($id);
  return view('post.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

**CommentController.php**

```
public function show($id)
{   
    $comments= Comment::find($id);
    return view('post.show')->with('comments', $comments);

}
```

**EDIT 1**

**Post.php**

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'description'];

    function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    function comment() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
```

}

Comment: you want to get the show view with two types of data right ?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid Essentially yes

Comment: so why not you making relation between two models?

Comment: use relationship between modals and visit this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly set the relationship between Post and Comment Model

In Post Model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

In Comment Model

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Post Controller

```
public function show($id)
{
  $post= Post::find($id);
  return view('post.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

Write in the blade file

```
<h1>{{$post->title}}</h1>
<p>Description: {{$post->description}}</p>

    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($post->comments as $comment)    //get all the comments related to this post
        <li>
          User: {{$comment->user_name}} <br>
          Comment: {{$comment->comment}} <br>
        </li><br>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Sunil. However, after implementing that I get a Undefined variable: post error?

Comment: I think you are not passing the $post variable to the blade file.

Comment: and i updated the code please check again!. @Jake2018

Comment: I now get

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @Jake2018 check your method name in Post Model. If it is comment() then write $post->comment and if it is comments() then write $post->comments.

Comment: I seen your Post Model function comment() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }  so in the foreach() loop you just change to $post->comments to $post->comment

Comment: Great. That's fixed it. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

**You can get both data by make relations between your models**

I think in your two models the relation would be like that,

**Post Model**

```
namespace App\Post;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

**Comment Model:**

```
namespace App\Comment;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
    }
}
```

so if you want to return the data to view then,

**PostController.php**

```
 public function show($id)
    {
      $post= Post::with('comments')->find($id);
      $data = [
            'post' => $post,
            'comments' => $post->comments,
      ];
      return view('post.show', $data);
    }
```

**CommentController.php**

```
 public function show($id)
{   
    $comments= Comment::with('post')->find($id);
    $data = [
        'post' => $comments->post,
        'comments' => $comments,
    ];
    return view('post.show' , $data);
}
```

For more details: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Comment: Thanks for that. However I get a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error for the show.blade.php file with this code

Comment: then it can be the problem of data. please debug using dd function when you returning the data in your view. example place dd($post);  before return in your show function in post controller